# How can I do the glydon pipe clip glitch on Super Mario Odyssey?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I got super mario odyssey and I know and I saw on YouTube if you capture a glydon and put it on a pipe in a way it is slanted you can jump/glide kinda and clip through a wall.

I saw many videos and did everything they told me to do but it is not working!

When I got the game I think it was version 1.2.0 (or something like that, I don't really pay attention to version types in games).

Comment: It's a good idea to check your game version regarding glitches since patches can remove glitches. It's not hard to check your game version either, and it shows that you've done some research - people generally prefer questions that people have put more effort into finding their answers, instead of ones that are easily solvable by checking your version and searching google. People are more likely to downvote your question otherwise (I didn't downvote btw).

Answer (score 6):

[It got patched out,](https://www.reddit.com/r/SuperMarioOdyssey/comments/7ztb1v/did_nintendo_patch_out_the_glydon_glitch/) so you can't do it on version 1.2.0.

I found that link as the second option from Google searching ["glydon pipe clip glitch"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=glydon%20pipe%20clip%20glitch&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU751AU751&oq=glydon%20pipe%20clip%20glitch&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3633j1j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - the first being this thread.

Comment: Worth noting: speedrunners no longer use this glitch because 1.3.0 has faster loading times, saving more time than the patched glitches from 1.0.0

Answer (score -1):

For context, 'Help a guest' is talking about a glitch where if you are on an angle with Glydon and then glide into a wall, you have the ability to sometimes glitch into walls. This glitch is showcased in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdAUP966JQk). This glitch **does** work in 1.2.0.

As far as I can tell, all you have to do is jump with Glydon at a slanted angle, glide into a wall, and when you touch the wall, hold forward. I hope this helped.

Comment: Whoa whoa! Marcus' answer is the more helpful answer to me. The other one was not as helpful because they thought I was talking about another, similar glitch. Marcus understood the glitch I was talking about.